# Marginalizing versus optimizing the nuisance and hyper parameters

Tags: bayesian, hyperparameter

In a Bayesian setting, the classical approach when studying a given variable of interest (here $\theta_0$) consists of marginalizing the full posterior over nuisance and hyper parameters (here $\theta_1$):
$$
p(\theta_0|x)=\int p(\theta_0,\theta_1|x) d \theta_1
$$
Nevertheless, an alternative cheaper approach consists in optimizing (e.g. MAP) over the hyperparameters/nuisance and then considering the density:
$$
p(\theta_{0},\theta_{1}^{MAP} |x).$$
**Question:** Are there some well-known limitations for either solution?

(Regardless of technical considerations.) For example, are there limitations when looking at the resulting mean or HPD interval?